What is Tapscript?
What is Tapscript?
How is it different from script? Is it the same thing as "Leaf script"?
How does it relate to Witness Script, miniscript and any other type of script used in Bitcoin transactions?
How and when was it implemented?
What can it be used for?

Script (uppercase S, also Bitcoin Script) is the scripting language used in Bitcoin. Its programs are called "scripts" (lowercase s), often with an adjective based on the location of the script in a transaction (output script, input script, redeem script, witness script, leaf script).
Leaf script is a script revealed as part of a Taproot (SegWit v1) script path spend (see BIP341).
Tapscript is a variant of Script used in leaf scripts with a leaf version of 0xc0 (see BIP342). It makes some significant changes to previously used Script, such as switching from ECDSA to Schnorr signatures, replacing OP_CHECKMULTISIG(VERIFY) with OP_CHECKSIGADD and introducing OP_SUCCESS opcodes for better upgradeability. Tapscript scripts are often called "tapscripts".
Miniscript is a language for writing scripts that enables composition, static analysis and more. It compiles directly to Script (or Tapscript).
Here is a diagram that relates all these terms together:


Great answer, might it also be worth mentioning [tag:miniscript]?

@Lee Feel free to add it to your question.

@VojtěchStrnad Very nice diagram! One tiny nit: if tapscript is a subclass (indirectly) of script, then that implies a script can be written in Tapscript... so should there be a "written in" arrow from script to Tapscript?

@PieterWuille Hmm, not sure if I like that. You can already see from the graph that some scripts are written in Tapscript, a direct connection might imply that all are (as with Script).

Fair enough, I guess that would change the meaning to "may be written in".
